# Issue regarding colors in splot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have `gnuplot` version 4.6 patchlevel 0 on Win XP 32bit. When I use `splot` in order to create three-dimensional plots, I encounter a problem and I would like to know if this is a bug of the new version. Let me explain the situation using a simple scenario.

```
set hidden
set isosamples 50
splot sin(x+y)
```

The function is working. However, it uses the default red color for all the parts (bottom and top) of the surface. In previous versions of `gnuplot`, the program used green color for the bottom and red for the top. Why this is not working in the latest version? Is this a bug?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've verified with gnuplot4.6.0 on OS-X.  However, the problem isn't there on gnuplot4.6.1 on Ubuntu Linux ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the 4.6 patchlevel 0 release.  According to the [release notes](http://www.gnuplot.info/announce.4.6.1) for 4.6 patchlevel 1, it has been fixed.

> - FIX top/bottom color distinction in hidden3d when not using palette/RGB colors