# gnuplot splot with hidden3d always colored, even with monochrome postscript option

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 4. I encountered the following problem:

```
set terminal postscript eps monochrome
set output "test.eps"
splot x*y
```

produces a monochrome plot as requested, but

```
set terminal postscript eps monochrome
set output "test.eps"
set hidden3d
splot x*y
```

produces a colored plot.

I'm pretty sure that worked with earlier gnuplot versions. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Thanks for your help!

(I saw that there was another problem with splot colors in an earlier version
([Issue regarding colors in splot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559395/issue-regarding-colors-in-splot)), was the new problem possibly introduced in the bug fix?)

Comment: Gnuplot version 5.0 patchlevel 0 appears to produce the same plot with either command.

Comment: I believe this is related to bug 1423 and you are correct that the previous fix caused this behavior (probably by requesting a specific line type that caused 1423 to cause this).  Bug 1423 has been fixed in version 5 allowing this to be corrected.  If possible, upgrading would be the best approach.